# RegEx in Dreamweaver

Tags: regex, dreamweaver

I know this is possible because I used to do this before... but I can't remember how!

I have a lot of text and paragraphs that I would like to wrap in `<p></p>` tags but I know you can do it very quickly using the find/replace feature using RegEx.

Can anyone refresh my memory? I'm using Dreamweaver.

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: What is your sample text and what is your expected output?

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 I just need to wrap unformatted text from a word processor with <p></p> tags. E.g. <p>Aenean eget purus molestie</p><p>Vestibulum neque leo</p> etc...

Comment: @Baz, How does the sample text look like before processing? Do you want it to have `<p>` tags on linebreaks?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it in Dreamweaver I think is to use the "Edit > Paste Special" menu, to past from a word processor with formatting.

If that doesn't work for you for some reason, you can use Dreamweaver search and replace with the "Use regular expressions" option enabled, and do a search and replace for:

```
\r|\n
```

and replace with

```
</p><p>
```

Then all that's needed is to add an outer paragraph tag if it's not already there.